Anime movie with a virus in Japan
I've watched an anime movie 6-7 years ago. It's about a part of Japan (I don't know exactly). That part of Japan is not infected by the virus/apocalypse and a team of trained military soldiers are given an assignment to go to there to examine the structure, but when they went to there they learn that all people became slaves. They were injected by a high-tech nano serum. 
It was an anime movie and basically a Japanese made one. I've been looking for this movie for more than 3 months.

Are ther other parts of Japan that are affected by "the virus/apocalypse"? When did you watch it? Could you tell the approx. year it was made?

@BenPlont actually I don't know the exact date. The other part of the world was affected by an apocalypse/virus. Japanese people thought that they would protect themselves from that apocalypse by building a huge wall surrounding Japan, and injecting a high tech serum.

add those details, and any other that you can remember to your question.

Maybe Vexille (2007)?  

Maria, the head of the resistance, details the 10 years of secrecy
  while SWORD studies Japan in shocked horror — the islands are a
  lifeless wasteland. In 2067, an unknown disease struck Japan and was
  countered by an experimental vaccine. In actuality, the disease was
  created by Daiwa and the "vaccine" was used as an excuse for Daiwa to
  begin testing experimental nanotechnology. Every Japanese citizen was
  converted into a form of synthetic life. But there were unforeseen
  side effects; the conversion was imperfect, resulting in the infected
  humans losing their free will and becoming just lifelike machines.
  Some of the nanotech went amok, creating the "Jags", giant whirling
  constructs of semisentient metal that prowl the wilderness. The Jags
  destroyed all of Japan, save Tokyo which is protected by an inedible
  wall of ceramic.

Site with lots of screencaps and commentary.

You are a god.

@Yagiz ^_^ Nah, just good at the Google.
